# full text search stored procedure get no results although relevant data exists

Tags: sql, angularjs, sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

A part of a project with one of our clients deals with creating full text indexes in Hebrew 1037 (Database has both english and hebrew in it) that will correspond with a UI system written in Angular and C# . The database itself is collated to Latin1_General_100_CI_AS. 
The stored procedure gets a parameter for search that suppose to get single word input and the code inside the SP uses that parameter for different full text search queries.

first weird thing that happens is that when i pass a string with or without quotation marks, everything works fine. I read that this is a known bug and Microsoft do not intend to fix it anytime soon.

The real problem lies with the actual string passed.

When i pass a string in Hebrew or a numeral value - everything works fine and the SQL Server fetches the relevant data (Through UI and SSMS).

When i pass a string in English through **SSMS**, SQL Server replies with a relevant data but when the UI system passes a parameter it gets no data back.

The following SQL code is the code im using which is very basic:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SearchByFreeText 
@StringToSearch NVARCHAR(500) = NULL

AS

SELECT *
FROM SampleTable
WHERE CONTAINS(SampleColumn, @StringToSearch)
OR 
FREETEXT(SampleColumn, @StringToSearch)
```

I will very appreciate some help on the matter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try To understand below diffrent :

1. SELECT * FROM content WHERE freetext(description,"SQL MGT")

   Although this appears to search on the string "SQL MGT," it actually searches on "SQL" or "MGT."
2. SELECT * FROM content WHERE CONTAINS(description, 'NT NEAR great')

   This search on the Description column finds all rows where "NT" is near "great".

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `language_term` explicitly when calling [CONTAINS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) or [FREETEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx). From the docs:

```
CONTAINS (... [ , LANGUAGE language_term ] )
```

> *language_term* is the language to use for word breaking, stemming, thesaurus expansions and replacements, and noise-word (or stopword) removal as part of the query.
>
> language_term can be specified as a string, integer, or hexadecimal value corresponding to the LCID of a language. If language_term is specified, the language it represents will be applied to all elements of the search condition. **If no value is specified, the column full-text language is used**.

Looks like you do have a FTS language mismatch and SSMS somehow manages to determine the correct one when you run your query in SSMS.

So, when passing English string from UI SQL Server probably tries to check it against Hebrew index. Not as final solution but try to hard code the English language code (1033) into SQL query and pass English search term from UI to see if anything will be found:

```
SELECT *
FROM SampleTable
WHERE CONTAINS(SampleColumn, @StringToSearch, LANGUAGE 1033)
OR 
FREETEXT(SampleColumn, @StringToSearch, LANGUAGE 1033)
```

If it does find results then you will probably have to determine the language of the search term on the fly and enable the correct `LANGUAGE` param via Dynamic SQL or `IF (@lang = 1033)` block.

HTH